# Image header CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem getting an image to show up in the header of my website. Any idea on how to get it to show up? The image file is also in the same folder as the html file so I really don't know why it's not showing up.

Here's the CSS file:

```
header {
width: 100%;
background-image: url("background1.jpg");
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: white;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: deeppink;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: pink;
}
```

And here's the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fnaf.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fnaf.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is the <header> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine, if you make reference to your `header` properly

```css
.header {  /* MODIFICATION */
width: 100%;
background-image: url("http://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/global/global-franchise-blue-header.jpg");
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: white;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: pink;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fnaf.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fnaf.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="header">       <!-- MODIFICATION -->
  <h1>My website name</h1> 
</div>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew the problem was simple!

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    background-image: url("../background1.jpg");
}
```

The thing is the `background-image` location is relative to the css file location which is in a `css` folder so it's searching for the file in the `css` folder while it should be looking one folder up (where the file is along with the html). Also it should be within the `body` selector rather than the `header` since it will be the background image for the entire body not the `header` which is not present in the html at all.